# setAttribute not finding ID that has been loaded with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a class "active" to a navbar item after having loaded the header from a different html file. I've been trying various ways of getting it to work, but none have been successful. The error I get is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null."

PS: I have a ready and onload functions just to try and make sure they are loaded in the right order. I did try having both in the same place, but it still didn't work. the console.logs are showing that the two items are executed in the right order.

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    let header = "http://ivanpenev.hopto.org/bootstrap/website/resources/header.html",
        footer = "http://ivanpenev.hopto.org/bootstrap/website/resources/footer.html";

    loadItems(header, footer);
});

window.onload = () => function() {
    let page = window.location.href.split("/").slice(-1)[0].split(".")[0]; //get file name
    active(page);
}

const loadItems = (header, footer) => {
    // Load the HTML contents of the header into <header>
    $('header').load(header);
    // Load the HTML contents of the footer into <footer>
    $('footer').load(footer);
    console.log('loaded');
}

const active = (page) => {
    console.log(page);

    document.getElementById(page).setAttribute('class', 'active');
}
```

here's the html file loaded in header:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="LOGO" height="52" width="362"></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li id="index"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li id="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li id="practices"><a href="practices.html">Practices</a></li>
                <li id="lawyers"><a href="lawyers.html">Our Lawyers</a></li>
                <li id="news"><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    </div>
</nav>
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only place you have `setAttribute` is within your active function. `load` is an asynchronous request meaning that it sends the request, continues on with the code, and then deals with the response whenever it comes back. It's likely when you use `setAttribute` the element doesn't exist yet. I am really confused by the retrieval of the window.location.href - `.load` shouldn't change the url in the navigation bar afaik ?

Comment: @zfrisch I use the same header in multiple html files, and i want to add an active class to the file I'm accessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load` is asynchronous. This means that even though they may appear to be in the right order, whatever is being done within each function can happen at any time. This likely ends up with you calling your `active` function **before** the header has been loaded.

I would suggest getting rid of your `onload` function and placing the same code within the **callback function** of the asynchronous load of your header. This is explained in the [.load() JQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function)

The callback simply does something **after** the load has been completed.

```
$('header').load(header, function() {
    let page = window.location.href.split("/").slice(-1)[0].split(".")[0]; //get file name
    active(page);
 });
```